# Expires header for specific file types

Tags: apache-2.2, http-headers

How can I add an expires header just for pngs, and the ico file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `ExpiresByType` directive of mod_expires.  [Docs here.](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_expires.html#expiresbytype)

```
ExpiresActive On

# expire after a month
ExpiresByType image/png A2592000
ExpiresByType image/x-icon A2592000
```

Answer (score 4):

Example (for the htaccess file):

```
# Cache the following content for 1 month (4 Weeks)
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2419200, public"
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Why is it `Cache-Control` and not `ExpiresByType`?

Comment: Both can be done, its about the target: (Target Files by Extension -> FilesMatch) ; (Target Files by MIME Type -> ExpiresByType). It is often easier to use a extension target rather then a MIME type. So if somebody messed up with the MIME config on the server, the filetype target is still working ;-).